# How To Install log.io?

Tags: log, monitoring

> How to install log.io on Ubuntu 12.04 & How do i configure log.io for logs ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Installation

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-devel

sudo apt-get update    

sudo apt-get install nodejs npm

sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev

sudo npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

#### Then

```
sudo npm install -g --prefix=/usr/local log.io
```

### Configuration

```
# cd /etc/log.io/
# ls
```

There are 2 file " **harvester.conf** "  " **server.conf** "

The **server.conf** got 2 configuration 1st you can change the port & 2nd one is you can configure it for authentication

```
/* Log.io log server configuration */

exports.config = {

  // Log server port
  port: 8998,   // < To Change The port

  // Uncomment to enable basic HTTP authentication
  /*
  basic_auth: {
    username: "foo",
    password: "bar"
  }
  */
}
```

Now 2nd one  **harvester.conf**

```
 /* Log.io log harvester configuration */

exports.config = {

  // Log server host & port
  server: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8998,
  },

  // Watch the following log files, defined by label:path mappings
  log_file_paths: {
                  logio_harvester: '/var/log/log.io/harvester.log'
                  },
  // To Monitor Auth Logs
  log_file_paths: {
              Auth_logs: '/var/log/auth.log'
          },
  // To Monitor Fail2ban Logs
 log_file_paths: {
                  Fail2ban_logs: '/var/log/fail2ban.log'
                  },
 // To Monitor Syslogs
 log_file_paths: {
                  Sys_logs: '/var/log/syslog'
                  },
   // Define name of current machine.
  // Alternatively, you can set this name in /etc/profile:
  // export LOGIO_HARVESTER_INSTANCE_NAME='my_log_machine'
  // If so, comment out the line below
  instance_name : 'log_node_1'
}
```

#### You can add as many logs path you want to

Now the last part

```
sudo log.io server start && sudo log.io harvester start
```

[log.io Installation On Ubuntu 12.04](https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io/wiki/v0.2.7-Build-Recipe-%28Ubuntu-12.04%29)

Comment: PPA https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: http://blog.gantrithor.com/post/10405024929/install-up-to-date-node-js-and-npm-on-ubuntu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214474/how-to-keep-up-with-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-in-ubuntu-ppa-compiling